# I try to write a function that returns the sum of two numbers. and this is my answer but on training they told me it is error

Tags: php

this is the question : 
Write a function that returns the sum of two numbers.

Example

For param1 = 1 and param2 = 2, the output should be
add(param1, param2) = 3.

Input/Output

[time limit] 4000ms (php)
[input] integer param1

Guaranteed constraints:
-100 ≤ param1 ≤ 1000.

[input] integer param2

Guaranteed constraints:
-100 ≤ param2 ≤ 1000.

[output] integer

The sum of the two inputs.

and this is my answer :

```
<?php 

function add($param1, $param2) {


    if ($param1 <= 1000 && $param1 >= -100 && $param2 <= 1000 && $param2 >= -100 ) {

        $sum = $param1 + $param2 ;
    }

    echo $sum;

}

add(100,2);

?>
```

Comment: Most obvious issue is that if the parameters fail the constraint test echoing `$sum` will not be defined and therefore generate an error

Comment: If you should **`return`** the sum of the two number - you better use **return**

Comment: there is no error on code . try it if you can . but this training website doesn't except it

Comment: In my opinion, "Guaranteed constraints" sounds more like they mean that they are telling you what the possible range of test inputs will be.

Comment: thank you @Dekel it is work now

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

function add($param1, $param2) {
    return $param1 + $param2;
}
```

Generally you want to *return* the answer. Also, I don't see anywhere in the description that you actually need to *enforce* those constraints. Your function should accept anything that makes sense. The constraints are there to let you know that you don't have to worry about overflows and underflows caused by the number type.